# Alfresco: "Access denied" when editing a document meta-data

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Having a document with a custom aspect and custom model, the manager of the site and the owner of the document (uploaded) cannot edit the custom inputs (inherited from the custom aspect) resulting in this error:

```
04050251 Access Denied. You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this operation.
```

How to let users edit the custom meta-data on the documents having a custom aspect ?

Stacktrace:

```
2014-05-06 17:01:06,357  ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-apr-80-exec-9] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 04060330 Access Denied.  You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this operation.
 org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.AccessDeniedException: 04060330 Access Denied.  You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this operation.
at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:50)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:161)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.alfresco.repo.model.filefolder.FilenameFilteringInterceptor.invoke(FilenameFilteringInterceptor.java:296)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.move(Unknown Source)
at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.MoveActionExecuter.executeImpl(MoveActionExecuter.java:86)
at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.ActionExecuterAbstractBase.execute(ActionExecuterAbstractBase.java:258)
at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.directActionExecution(ActionServiceImpl.java:838)
at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.CompositeActionExecuter.executeImpl(CompositeActionExecuter.java:66)
at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.ActionExecuterAbstractBase.execute(ActionExecuterAbstractBase.java:258)
at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.directActionExecution(ActionServiceImpl.java:838)
at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeActionImpl(ActionServiceImpl.java:738)
at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeAction(ActionServiceImpl.java:572)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor904.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.invoke(AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:46)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:161)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.executeAction(Unknown Source)
at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleServiceImpl.executeAction(RuleServiceImpl.java:1250)
at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleServiceImpl.executeRule(RuleServiceImpl.java:1244)
at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleServiceImpl.executePendingRule(RuleServiceImpl.java:1190)
at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleServiceImpl.executePendingRulesImpl(RuleServiceImpl.java:1119)
at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleServiceImpl.executePendingRules(RuleServiceImpl.java:1092)
at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleTransactionListener.beforeCommit(RuleTransactionListener.java:57)
at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.AlfrescoTransactionSupport$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.doBeforeCommit(AlfrescoTransactionSupport.java:737)
at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.AlfrescoTransactionSupport$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.doBeforeCommit(AlfrescoTransactionSupport.java:717)
at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.AlfrescoTransactionSupport$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.beforeCommit(AlfrescoTransactionSupport.java:683)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit  (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:927)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:737)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning   (TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
at org.alfresco.util.transaction.SpringAwareUserTransaction.commit(SpringAwareUserTransaction.java:472)
at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:474)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:491)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:529)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:341)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1810)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
 Caused by: net.sf.acegisecurity.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied.
at net.sf.acegisecurity.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:86)
at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:398)
at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:77)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:46)
... 75 more
```

Comment: Pls add the full stack trace. Do you have a rule or behavior that is triggered by your custom aspect & tries to perform sth. the user is not allowed to do.

Comment: Can they edit the default meta-data? Like cm:description?

Comment: The custom aspect and custom model likely have nothing to do with this problem. Check the permissions on the node.